# es6 import var not defined in code importing

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

For some reason when I do var sphere = new Core(); in Game, I see Core is undefined, even though I import it:

Game.js

```
  import Core from 'gameUnits/Core' 

    export class Game { 
    constructor() {
```

Core.js:

```
export class Core {
    constructor(scene) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

When you make import without curly brackets you're trying to import **default** object of the module.

So, you must add `default` keyword to your `Core` exporting:

```
export default class Core {
    constructor(scene) {
    }
}
```

**OR** place your `Core` importing into curly brackets:

```
import { Core } from 'gameUnits/Core';
```

Look [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for more informaction about ECMAScript 6 modules

**PS**: Using `default` keyword you can specify ANY name for `Core` class. For example:

```
import GameUnitsCore from 'gameUnits/Core';
```