# How to use ES6 module system in my case?

Tags: ecmascript-6

All:

I am pretty new to ES6 module system, say I have files like:

**cmod.js**

```
export var name = "hello2";
```

**main.js**

```
import name from './cmod.js';
console.log(name);
```

After I run transpile :

```
babel ./*.js  --out-dir js/ --watch
```

I wonder why the result is undefined? Could any
I tried to find answer from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

But it seems too complicated to me to match my case.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 import var not defined in code importing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741566/es6-import-var-not-defined-in-code-importing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exporting a named export, but importing the default one. You should be using either

```
// cmod.js
export var name = "hello2";
// useful for multiple exports
```

```
// main.js
import { name } from './cmod.js';
console.log(name);
```

or

```
// cmod.js
export default "hello2";
// useful for single-value exports
```

```
// main.js
import name from './cmod.js';
console.log(name);
```